# Adding to Content Query Snippet

Tags: content-query-web-part, snippet, sharepont

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to edit a content query HTML Snippet.

I am creating a page layout in SharePoint designer, and a using the snippet editor to create the Snippet code to drop into the page layout, to display 4 items from a list, but I want to be able to wrap those items within some html code, for example to place within bootstrap columns, is it possible?

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you do this, yes, it is possible.

If your four items in the list are within a webpart (Remember WPQ1 is the body area of the page itself) you can view the page in the web browser and then Edit the page. Click within the area where your list is located, edit webpart if a CEWP or similar, and then click Edit Source from the ribbon. This will open a HTML editor that will allow you to input scripts, css, and html code.

It will depend on where you put it, and how you are building it. I am sure you can do the same thing within SPD, but I do not have as much experience building with that tool as I do with the web tools.

Good luck